# JPA QL "IN" collection doesn't work for openjpa 1.2.2

Tags: jpa, openjpa

JPA 1 with OpenJPA 1.2.2 in a unit-test backed Hsqldb 1.8. The following JPA QL doesn't work with a "IN" on a List of ids doesn't work.

```
@Transactional
public void updateSettlementId(List<Long> voucherIds, Long settlementId) {
    String query = "UPDATE VoucherProcessed vp SET vp.settlement.id=:settlementId where vp.voucher.id IN (:voucherIds)";
    em.createQuery(query).setParameter("settlementId", settlementId)
            .setParameter("voucherIds", StringUtils.join(voucherIds.iterator(), ","))
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [UPDATE VOUCHER_PROCESSED t0 SET t1.settlement_id = ? WHERE (t0.voucher_id IN (?))]

VOUCHER_PROCESSED table is being created in hsqldb while the test is run so the above error seems erroneous and misleading.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can anyone point out how code formatter is supposed to work here?

Comment: I corrected formatting, check out [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: try Databasename.TABLENAME also you dont need to use StringUtils, Query[1] setParameterList takes a collection, last time i checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  .setParameter("voucherIds", voucherIds)
```

works with Hibernate, but (please correct me if I'm wrong) JPA specification does not <strike>define `IN` construct</strike> allow using collection in `setParameter()` for queries like "`IN (:voucherIds)`", it is vendor specific.

Comment: @priya I can actually confirm that the proposed solution works in OpenJPA 1.2.2, you only need to supply the list of Longs directly.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz It does. Chapter 4.6.8 "IN expressions" of "JSR 220: EJB Version 3.0, Java Persistence API" (JPA 1.0).

Comment: I edited my answer, I didn't mean `IN` statement but using collection in `setParameter()`, my mistake, sorry. Of course JPA allows you to use `IN` in queries, thanks for pointing out the spec.